# Exception java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 24 bytes using DESede

Tags: java, exception, encryption, key, des

I know that this question is often asked but I have checked everything I found in Stack Overflow and did not find the solution to my problem.
i am using DESede for encryption and decryption and taking external 24 byte key input. but getting exception.

here is my code:

```
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
    import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

    public class DESede {

     private static Cipher encryptCipher;
     private static Cipher decryptCipher;

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeySpecException {
      try {


       String desKey = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"; // value from user
       byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(desKey);
       System.out.println((int)keyBytes.length);

       SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
       SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes));

       encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
       encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); //throwing Exception
       byte[] encryptedData = encryptData("Confidential data");

       decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
       decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
       decryptData(encryptedData);

      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

     }
```

//method for encryption

```
     private static byte[] encryptData(String data)
       throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
      System.out.println("Data Before Encryption :" + data);
      byte[] dataToEncrypt = data.getBytes();
      byte[] encryptedData = encryptCipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
      System.out.println("Encryted Data: " + encryptedData);

      return encryptedData;
     }
```

//method for decryption

```
     private static void decryptData(byte[] data)
       throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
      byte[] textDecrypted = decryptCipher.doFinal(data);
      System.out.println("Decryted Data: " + new String(textDecrypted));
     }
    }
```

i am getting exception at the line: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 24 bytes

```
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
```

any one have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Note : With JDK-8 the error is : `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm: DES required`. With JDK-6, error is as noted above : `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 24 bytes`. Will update if I identify for JDK-7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two mistakes you have done in your code

you use `DESede` to create the secret key factory in this line

```
 SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
```

but you use the `DES` to get the `Cipher` object. you have to use `DESede` instead

so use this line

`encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`

instead of this line

`encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");`

use the same algorithm to get decripting cipher

and another one is use a `AlgorithmParameterSpec` to init the decrypting cipher.

```
byte iv[] = encryptCipher.getIV(); 
IvParameterSpec dps = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, dps);
```

you can use above code to apply the `AlgorithmParameterSpec` to the initialization of cipher

Comment: i have done ur changes, now the same exception is thrown in line `decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, dps);`

Comment: did you change this line `decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");` to this line `decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`?

Comment: this line `byte iv[] = encryptCipher.getIV();` is throwing **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException** when decrypting the string from swing application, which is encrypted from jsp module with same algorithm. and vice versa. but if use swing to swing or jsp to jsp, then working. other AES,DES are working when swing to jsp or jsp to swing. but this is not. any idea why this is happening? thanks for your time..